# woocommerce site behind Nginx - Ajaxfy Admin bar

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have woocommerce site behind Nginx.

im using Nginx proxy cache and i ajaxfy all the personalization sections.

but i want that the admin bar will appear to the admin user's.
for now i disable the admin bar.

any ideas?

Thanks,
Elad

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you want the admin bar to appear only for admin users.
You should add this to your functions.php file.
And also, you should have enabled the admin bar.

```
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Comment: no... i have server cache that mean that i cant render the admin bar on the server side. i need to get it with ajax